# How to map symbols to the words in elasticsearch using mappings?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

Used the following code but when searched for C++, its not recognizing ++ symbol.

Any filters available for such mappings?

```
{
    "onnet_taxonomy":{
        "aliases":{

        },
        "mappings":{
            "text":{
                "properties":{
                    "Occupation":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                            "keyword":{
                                "type":"keyword",
                                "ignore_above":256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Skill":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                            "keyword":{
                                "type":"keyword",
                                "ignore_above":256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Skill Type":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                            "keyword":{
                                "type":"keyword",
                                "ignore_above":256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "keywords":{
                "properties":{
                    "Occupation":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                            "keyword":{
                                "type":"keyword",
                                "ignore_above":256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Skill":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                            "analyzed":{
                                "type":"text",
                                "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword",
                                "search_analyzer":"analyzer_shingle"
                            },
                            "keyword":{
                                "type":"keyword",
                                "ignore_above":256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Skill Type":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                            "keyword":{
                                "type":"keyword",
                                "ignore_above":256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings":{
            "index":{
                "number_of_shards":"5",
                "provided_name":"onnet_taxonomy",
                "creation_date":"1583114276039",
                "analysis":{
                    "filter":{
                        "my_shingle_filter":{
                            "max_shingle_size":"8",
                            "min_shingle_size":"2",
                            "output_unigrams":"true",
                            "type":"shingle"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer":{
                        "analyzer_keyword":{
                            "filter":[
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "char_filter":[
                                "code_mapping"
                            ],
                            "type":"custom",
                            "tokenizer":"keyword"
                        },
                        "analyzer_shingle":{
                            "filter":[
                                "lowercase",
                                "my_shingle_filter"
                            ],
                            "char_filter":[
                                "code_mapping"
                            ],
                            "tokenizer":"standard"
                        }
                    },
                    "char_filter":{
                        "code_mapping":{
                            "type":"mapping",
                            "mappings":[
                                "++ => plusplus",
                                "c# => csharp",
                                "C# => csharp",
                                "F# => fsharp",
                                "f# => fsharp",
                                ".net => dotnet",
                                ".Net => dotnet",
                                ".NET => dotnet",
                                "( => map_lp",
                                ") => map_rp",
                                "& => and",
                                "# => hash",
                                "+ => plus"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas":"1",
                "uuid":"LNf2frW1S8WmHSOJWVrvLA",
                "version":{
                    "created":"5030399"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to format you code correctly.

Comment: Could you please share the query you've tried. Also a sample document would be useful.